# Anyway to push a user's last commit via git through github?

Tags: ubuntu, git, github

I have a Organization account through github, and we recently had to remove a user from the organization.

- The user never pushed up the last bit of changes they made.
- We do not have access to the actual github account the user used.
- We do however have access to the server they worked on.

The problem is the user made a commit without a push, and attempting to do a push on the server in their former working environment fails since the we don't have that github account's credentials.

I have is admin rights/ownership rights to the organization account so I am wondering if anyone knows of anything I can do through git to override the credentials?

Am I unfortunately going to be stuck doing some lengthy manual diffing of everything to track changes otherwise and figure out what's in what commit this person has ever made, since they have made many - just never pushing those changes up/out?

Comment: `commit` doesn't  write the changes to the github server, `push` does. if he only commited, then the files are only avaialble on the envoirnment that he did the changes(its normally his PC)

Comment: yes, I know the commit doesn't write to the server.. Im looking to push those files up to the github server as the "final commit" from the user so its not a complete waste. Problem is they have touched so many files and only ever made commits, and every time you make a commit you don't see what changes out right are going upstream

Comment: even if its not as the other person.. If I can switch the credentials on the .git so it asks me for another user/pass rather than that person. So I can just do it

Comment: hmm, mate its a long shot, u may want to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git